# How to exclude LICENSE files in sbt-android-sdk plugin?

Tags: android, scala, sbt

I am using https://github.com/pfn/android-sdk-plugin to build my Android app with Scala. When I ran `sbt android:package`, I got this error:

```
com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE
    File 1: ...ivy2\cache\org.apache.httpcomponents\httpcore\jars\httpcore-4.0.1.jar
    File 2: ...ivy2\cache\org.apache.httpcomponents\httpcore\jars\httpcore-4.0.1.jar
```

I searched for a while, and people say I can set a `packageOptions` to exclude the licenses. But I am new to Scala, and have no idea how to do so.

Comment: Can you provide your `build.sbt` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
apkbuildExcludes in Android += "META-INF/LICENSE.txt"
```

In your case "META-INF/LICENSE".

https://github.com/pfn/android-sdk-plugin

See new features section.

Comment: This fixed it for me - note this just goes in your main build.sbt. I also found that NOTICE.txt files were problematic, so I used:
apkbuildExcludes in Android ++= Seq(
  "META-INF/LICENSE.txt",
  "META-INF/NOTICE.txt"
)

Comment: In the latest version of the android scala plugin. _apkbuildExcludes_ key is deprecated and packingOptions is used for excludes. `packagingOptions in Android := PackagingOptions(
  Seq.empty[String],
  Seq(
    "META-INF/LICENSE",
    "META-INF/LICENSE.txt",
    "META-INF/NOTICE",
    "META-INF/NOTICE.txt"),
  Seq.empty[String])`

Comment: In the latest version of the android scala plugin. _apkbuildExcludes_ key is deprecated and packingOptions is used for excludes. `packagingOptions in Android := PackagingOptions(Seq( "META-INF/LICENSE", "META-INF/LICENSE.txt", "META-INF/NOTICE", "META-INF/NOTICE.txt"))`

Answer (score 0):

A trick from https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61573#c14 solved my problem:

```
find .../path/to/package/caches/ -iname "*.jar" -exec zip -d '{}' 'META-INF/*' \;
```

In *gradle* they have:

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }
}
```

May be the plugin can do `packageOptions in Adroid += exclude("...")`? Since I have already applied the trick, I can no longer verify this idea.